# ssl.SSLContext.keylog_filename not creating file

Tags: ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I work with Python 3.9.12 and I am writing a code that sends API requests from a server. I need the SSL keys to decrypt the traffic for debug. There are two methods to extract the the SSL keys: using `sslkeylog.set_keylog()` or `ssl.SSLContext.keylog_filename`. However, only the first method works for me and I don't know why

```
#This method with sslkeylog works. The file "secrets.log" is generated
import sslkeylog
import os
import requests
os.environ["SSLKEYLOGFILE"] = "secrets.log"
sslkeylog.set_keylog("secrets.log")
req = requests.get('https://google.com')

#This method with ssl doesn't work. The file "secrets.log" is NOT generated
import ssl
import os
import requests
os.environ["SSLKEYLOGFILE"] = "secrets.log"
ssl.SSLContext.keylog_filename = "secrets.log"
req = requests.get('https://google.com')
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For the second method, this should be enough:

```python
import os
import requests

os.environ["SSLKEYLOGFILE"] = "secrets.log"
req = requests.get('https://google.com')
```

It works with python 3.8.10.